# Flutter emoji font working om iOS emulator, but not on real device

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter, emoji

I downloaded and put the [`NotoColorEmoji-Regular.ttf`](https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Color+Emoji) in the assets and configured it in the pubspec.yml

```
    - family: NotoColorEmoji
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Noto_Color_Emoji/NotoColorEmoji-Regular.ttf
```

I am using it like this:

```
Text(emoji,
  style: const TextStyle(
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
    fontSize: 22,
    height: 1,
    fontFamily: 'NotoColorEmoji',
    color: const Color(0xFF191919),
  ),
)
```

This works on

- Android emulator
- Android device
- iOS emulator (iOS 15.5, iphone 13)

It does not work on

- a real **device iOS 12.5.5, iphone 6**. Everything else of the app works fine on the device, but the font is not working (i.e. nothing shows up but an emoji is expected).
- Unfortunately I have no other real iphone device for testing => Can anyone confirm or disprove the behavior on other real devices?

I tried

- uninstall the app from the device
- `flutter clean`
- re-install the app (`flutter run`)
- run the app from xcode

I found

- https://github.com/googlefonts/noto-emoji/issues/72 which indicates that macOS does not support the ttf format, but Apple would compile the ttf using a SBIX format, which does not support CBDT/CBLC as used by the NotoColorEmoji font. But I could not figure out if that would be an issue with iOS? And also I wonder because on the emulator it runs fine.

### EDIT

As a workaround we currently use the system font on ios:

```
TextStyle textEmoji(BuildContext context) {
  return TextStyle(
    fontFamily: Platform.isIOS
      ? null // see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74710185/flutter-emoji-font-working-om-ios-emulator-but-not-on-real-device
      : 'NotoColorEmoji',
    // ...
  );
}
```

Comment: Please did you end up ever getting a solution to this? 
Having same problem where emojis don't show up. My test device iPhone Xr and iOS 16.2.
Everything working as expected on android and web, but the emojis just do not show up on iOS.

Comment: Not yet. Our temporary solution is to use Noto only on android and use the default apple font on iOS. Eventually, we will use our own icon font in the long-term.

Comment: Thanks, I figured that might be the case. I'll do the same and use the default font. Do the emojis show up on ios as expected or was there anything else you had to do?

Comment: I added our `TextStyle` workaround to the bottom of the question. We had nothing else todo.

Answer (score 0):

*Edit*: I just realised that you were talking about a different font, still leaving this here in case it may be helpful to someone

---

Just for anyone reading this now, it seems to be fixed on iOS. I used the https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Emoji font in my flutter app and it works on my iOS release builds ✨

In `pubspec.yaml`

```
-fonts: 
    - family: NotoEmoji
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/NotoEmoji-VariableFont_wght.ttf
          weight: 400
```

I also created a widget for the emoji:

```
class Emoji extends StatelessWidget {
      final String emoji;
      final TextStyle? style;
      final EdgeInsets padding;
    
      const TextEmoji(
        emoji, {
        this.style,
        this.padding = EdgeInsets.zero,
      });
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        final theme = Provider.of<MyThemeData>(context);
        final emojiStyle = TextStyle(
          fontSize: theme.dimensions.emojiFontSize,
          fontFamily: 'NotoEmoji',
          color: theme.myColors.emojiText(),
        );
        return Padding(
          padding: padding,
          child: Text(
            emoji,
            style: style != null ? emojiStyle.merge(style) : emojiStyle,
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```